# JButton.isSelected() if statement not changing JOptionPane variable

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I've been working on a JPanel quiz-type program and I want to use isSelected() with an if statement to display a different String and ImageIcon on a JOptionPane once the quiz is completed based on the options selected. When compiling there are no errors; however when I run the quiz the JOptionPane appears but remains blank.

I've declared the String and ImageIcon variables as such:

```
public class MBTIgame1
{
//some JPanel stuff omitted
public static ImageIcon cart;
public static String desc;
```

My if statements appear like this:

```
if (button1.isSelected() && button5.isSelected() && button9.isSelected())
    {String desc = new String("<html>INTJ<br>Ni: Introverted Intuition<br> Te: Extroverted Thinking<br> Fi: Extroverted Intuition<br> Se: Extroverted Sensing<br>");
     ImageIcon cart = new ImageIcon("intj.png");};
```

And my JOptionPane result appears as so:

```
class AddButton10Listener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        responses[4] = 2;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, desc, "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, cart);
    }
}
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

Based on...

```
if (button1.isSelected() && button5.isSelected() && button9.isSelected( {
    String desc = new String("<html>INTJ<br>Ni: Introverted Intuition<br> Te: Extroverted Thinking<br> Fi: Extroverted Intuition<br> Se: Extroverted Sensing<br>");
    ImageIcon cart = new ImageIcon("intj.png");
};
```

`desc` an `cart` are defined as local variables, so the variables that are been used here...

```
class AddButton10Listener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        responses[4] = 2;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, desc, "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, cart);
    }
}
```

are probably `null` or still what ever default value you applied to them when they were initialised

Comment: Thank you to both you and @Hovercraftfullofeels . Very insightful advice. I'm moving from functional programming to object-oriented and needless to say there are quite a few things that trip me up. :)

Comment: @E.Jole Hahaha, I'm moving from OO to FP, I feel your ... joy 

Answer (score 3):

While all class that descend from the AbstractButton have an `isSelected()` method, including the JButton class, this method only really makes sense when used with buttons that are *selectable* -- JToggleButton, JRadioButton and JCheckBox. These three classes have two different states, selected and non-selected that are are readily visible and which can be easily listened for with an ItemListener. JButtons are better used to listen for presses using an ActionListener.

So you must decide -- do you want to use one of the 3 selectable buttons, the JToggleButton, JRadioButton or JCheckBox and listen for changes to selection state using an ItemListener, or do you want to use a JButton and listen for button presses using an ActionListener? Your programming needs will dictate this decision.

Comment: Yes, and also what MadProgrammer states is correct. 1+ to his answer as well!